# decoding html entity not working for ajax,javascript and jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am saving html data itno mysql database.I am encoding my html data by this method

```
$html = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(
        html_entity_decode($_POST['html'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
    )));
```

But when I am fetching data,back from databse,my  scripts looks weird and nothing works.
This is how I am again decoding when taking data from database.
Its what I am getting back

```
'&lt;head&gt;\n  &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;\n        &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Pragma&quot; content=&quot;no-cache&quot;&gt;\n    &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Expires&quot; content=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;link href=&quot;css/style.css&quot; rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;script src=&quot;js/jquery.min.js&quot;&gt;\n        &lt;/script&gt;\n &lt;/head&gt;\n    \n    \n &lt;body style=&quot;background-image: url(http://localhost:8019/SGMC/Images/bg_1.png);&quot;&gt;\n  &lt;div class=&quot;header&quot;&gt; \n         &lt;a style=&quot;margin-left:45%; \n               margin-top:5px; \n                        line-height:50px&quot;&gt;\n               SGMC Portal\n            &lt;/a&gt; \n            \n            &lt;a class=&quot;button&quot; style=&quot;float:right; \n                 top:0px;\n                    margin-right:20px;\n                    font-size:14px;&quot; href=&quot;home.php&quot;&gt;\n                    \n                &lt;img src=&quot;Images/home_icon.png&quot; alt=&quot;Home&quot; id=&quot;homelogo&quot;&gt;\n            &lt;/a&gt;\n            \n     &lt;ul id=&quot;headerright&quot;&gt;\n       &lt;li&gt; \n                 &lt;img src=&quot;Images/user_icon.png&quot; id=&quot;userlogo&quot; alt=&quot;User Icon&quot;&gt;\n         \n                     \n          \n     Default           \n                     \n          &lt;img src=&quot;Images/down_arrow.png&quot; alt=&quot;Choose&quot;&gt;\n                    \n                    &lt;ul id=&quot;dropdown&quot;&gt;\n                     &lt;li&gt;\n                         &lt;a href=&quot;devices.php&quot;&gt;\n                             &lt;div&gt;Devices&lt;/div&gt;\n                            &lt;/a&gt;\n                        &lt;/li&gt;\n            &lt;li&gt;\n                         &lt;a href=&quot;configurations.php&quot;&gt;\n                          &lt;div&gt;Configuration&lt;/div&gt;\n                            &lt;/a&gt;\n                        &lt;/li&gt;\n            &lt;li&gt;\n                         &lt;a href=&quot;settings.php&quot;&gt;\n                             &lt;div&gt;Settings&lt;/div&gt;\n                            &lt;/a&gt;\n                        &lt;/li&gt;\n            &lt;li&gt;\n                         &lt;a href=&quot;logout.php&quot;&gt;\n                             &lt;div&gt;Log Out&lt;/div&gt;\n                            &lt;/a&gt;\n                        &lt;/li&gt;\n          &lt;/ul&gt;\n       &lt;/li&gt;\n     &lt;/ul&gt;\n  &lt;/div&gt;\n \n \n\n\n &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;xsdfile/stl.css&quot;&gt;\n &lt;script src=&quot;xsdfile/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n &lt;script&gt;\n function gen(hidden_id,div_id,min,max,btn_id)\n { \n  \n  \n  var counter=parseInt(document.getElementById(hidden_id).value);\n  if(max==&quot;unbounded&quot;)\n  {  counter=counter+1;\n    document.getElementById(hidden_id).value=counter;  \n    var xmlhttp;\n    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)\n      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari\n      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();\n      }\n    else\n      {// code for IE6, IE5\n      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject(&quot;Microsoft.XMLHTTP&quot;);\n      }\n    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()\n      {\n      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 &amp;&amp; xmlhttp.status==200)\n        {\n        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;\n        }\n      }\n    xmlhttp.open(&quot;GET&quot;,&quot;xsdfile/form.php?counter=&quot;+counter,true);\n    xmlhttp.send();\n   $(function(){$(&#039;#&#039;+btn_id).remove();});\n  }\n  else \n  { \n   var len=$(&#039;div[id^=complexType_]&#039;).length;\n   if(len&lt;max)\n   {\n    counter=counter+1;\n    document.getElementById(hidden_id).value=counter;  \n    var xmlhttp;\n    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)\n      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari\n      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();\n      }\n    else\n      {// code for IE6, IE5\n      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject(&quot;Microsoft.XMLHTTP&quot;);\n      }\n    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()\n      {\n      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 &amp;&amp; xmlhttp.status==200)\n        {\n        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;\n        }\n      }\n    xmlhttp.open(&quot;GET&quot;,&quot;xsdfile/form.php?counter=&quot;+counter,true);\n    xmlhttp.send();\n    \n    $(function(){$(&#039;#&#039;+btn_id).remove();});\n   }\n   else\n   {\n   alert(&quot;Maximum fields are already opended&quot;);\n   }\n   \n   \n  }\n \n \n\n }\n  function addField(complex_name,div_id,hidden_id,txtBox_id,min,max,count)\n  {\n   var name=txtBox_id.substring(0, txtBox_id.length - 9);\n   \n   var a=parseInt(document.getElementById(hidden_id).value);\n   \n   if(a+min&lt;max+1)\n   {\n    \n     document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML +=&#039;&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;&#039;+complex_name+&#039;[&#039;+count+&#039;].&#039;+name+&#039;[]&quot; id=&#039;+txtBox_id+(min+a)+&#039; &gt;&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; id=&quot;remove_&#039;+txtBox_id+(a+min)+&#039;&quot; value=&quot;-&quot; style=&quot;width:30px;position:relative;left:5px;&quot; onclick=&quot;removeField(\\&#039;remove_&#039;+txtBox_id+(a+min)+&#039;\\&#039;,\\&#039;&#039;+txtBox_id+(min+a)+&#039;\\&#039;,\\&#039;&#039;+hidden_id+&#039;\\&#039;)&quot;&gt; &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#039;;\n    document.getElementById(hidden_id).value=(a+1);\n   }\n   else\n   {\n    alert(&quot;Maximum fields are already opended&quot;);\n   }\n   \n  }\n  function removeField(btn_id,txtBox_id,hidden_id)\n  {\n   $(function(){\n    $(&#039;#&#039;+txtBox_id).remove();\n    $(&#039;#&#039;+btn_id).remove();\n   });\n   document.getElementById(hidden_id).value=parseInt(document.getElementById(hidden_id).value)-1;\n  }\n  function removeComplexType(div_id,btn_id)\n  {\n   $(function(){\n    $(&#039;#&#039;+div_id).remove();\n    $(&#039;#&#039;+btn_id).remove();\n   });\n  }\n &lt;/script&gt;\n \n\n\n\n&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;xsdfile/form2object.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n\n&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;xsdfile/json2.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n\n&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;\n\n function test()\n\n {\n  var formData = form2object(&#039;testForm&#039;, &#039;.&#039;, true,\n\n    function(node)\n\n    {\n\n     if (node.id &amp;&amp; node.id.match(/callbackTest/))\n\n     {\n      return { name: node.id, value: node.innerHTML };\n     }\n\n    });\n  $(function() {\n    htmlData = $(&quot;html&quot;).html();\n   \n  });\n   \n  jsonString=JSON.stringify(formData, null, &#039;\\t&#039;);\n  confName=document.getElementById(&quot;configuration_name..
```

I am encoding this by this method.

```
$html_data = html_entity_encode($arr[0]);
```

This code is working fine for html elements,but still my script not working as still some characters are not yet removed.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is not a very good idea to try to roll your own sanitization schemes. Have a look at [PDO](http://us2.php.net/pdo).

Comment: `addslashes()` is about as useful for preventing sql injection attacks as a piece of wet toilet paper is as a rope: it's UTTERLY USELESS.

Comment: Whatever,but still I am bound to do this,Please help.How to remove characters from scripts also